# Provide an html UI within nuget package

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

Ive made a small Application that will be published in a nuget package.

Additional to my C# code i made a little html UI for administrative purposes.

Now i would like this html files to be placed in the new Project Explorer if this is possible?

To build the package ive downloaded the CreateNewNuGetPackageFromProjectAfterEachBuild Package.

Would be nice if someone has an idea how i can solve this.

Best Regards
Andre

Answer (score 0):

You can have content files in a NuGet package that are added to a project. This is documented in the [NuGet nuspec reference documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/Create/NuSpec-Reference).

For NuGet version 2 you can use a files element with a Content attribute:

```
<file src="css\mobile\*.css" target="content\css\mobile" />
```

This will create a css\mobile directory inside the project when the NuGet package is added.

With NuGet 3 in Visual Studio 2015 update 1 the new recommendation is to use a contentFiles if you need to support the newer project types that use a project.json file. Note that the recommendation is that these files are immutable and are not to be modified by a developer.

```
<contentFiles>
    <files include="any/any/images/abc.png" buildAction="EmbeddedResource" />
```